# Fetching data with axios in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, get-request

I'm new in react so I'm trying to make a get request with axios in react with a service to get a track and the respective races from it, but I got track like a empty object. I need to know how to make the get request efficiently.

**trackUtils.js**

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import ActionTypes from '../constants/AppConstants';
import config from '../../config';
import axios from 'axios';

class trackUtil {

    constructor() {
        this.serverConfig = config.ServiceConfig;
        this.baseURL = this.serverConfig.url + ':' + this.serverConfig.port + '/';
        this.appConfig = config.AppConfig;
    }

    trackRequest(data) {
        const url = this.baseURL + 'BusRace/GetRacesTrack';

        axios.get(url)
            .then((response ) =>  {
                AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                    type: ActionTypes.GET_TRACK,
                    data: { ...response.data.tracks }
                });
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

}

export default new trackUtil();
```

**ConfigStore.js**

```
import { ReduceStore } from 'flux/utils';
import ActionTypes from '../constants/AppConstants';
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import config from '../../config';


class ConfigStore extends ReduceStore {

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            language: config.SiteConfig.defaultLanguage,
            languageLabels: {},
            tracks : {}

        };
    }

    reduce(state, action) {

        switch (action.type) {
            case ActionTypes.GET_TRACK:
                var newState = Object.assign({}, state);
                newState.tracks = action.data;
                return newState;
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
}

export default new ConfigStore(AppDispatcher);
```

**EDIT**
Adding from my component Body.js

```
static getStores() {
    return [ConfigStore];
};

static calculateState() {
    let configData = ConfigStore.getState();
    return {
        configInfo: configData,
        local: {"lineTypesDropTitle": ""}
    };
};

componentDidMount() {

    const params = {...this.state, ...{actionType: ActionTypes.GET_TRACK}};
    ActionCreators.actionTrigger(params);
}
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: you should console `response.data.tracks` instead of `data` to check the data response from the server. And `{...response.data.tracks}` is equal to`response.data.tracks`

Comment: Thank you, but now I got tracks as undefined

Comment: Then the server gave you data without `tracks` property? You should check the data response structure before dispatch it. like `console.log(response)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Redux or other state management usually a good place to fetch data is `componentDidMount()`, so you define your component with it's initial state, once the component is mounted the axios call is made and once the data is resolved you update the state. Something like this.

```
class MyAwesomeComponent extends Component{
    //Defining initial state
    state ={
        data : null
    }

    //Making the API call and once resolved updating the state
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('myendpoint').then( res => this.setState({data : res})
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using redux

Comment: `componentDidMount()` still is a good place to do that, but with redux what you want to do is centralize your application's state and serialize state to props in componentDidMount

Comment: I have it in my body.js component, edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Quick thing I noticed was "BusRace/GetRacesTrack" is that correct? not maybe "BusRace/GetRaceTracks", you do refer to tracks as plural in your question.

Comment: The method get a track and his respective races, thank you for the observation, question already edited.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dupocas answer you can also use a functional component for this:

```js
const MyAwesomeComponent = () => {
    //Defining initial state
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    //Making the API call and once resolved updating the state
    useEffect(() => axios.get('myendpoint').then( res => setData(res)), [])
}
```