# Why inside the then() the data exist, and out side doesn't - Axios returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios, response

The code is:

```
var data;

axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
    data = result;  
    console.log(data); //This work
    return data;
});

console.log(data)//this don't work
```

The goal is to get the answer from axios to use in the component where this code is. However, I can't get this information out of the Then () function. Sometimes it returns undefined, and if you do:

```
    var data;

    data = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
        return result
    });

    console.log(data)//this don't work
```

It's return "Promise {  }"

I already tryed:

1

```
    async function  getData(){
        var response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
            return result
        });

        return response
    }

    var data = getData();

    console.log(data);
```

2

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
   
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
        setData(result);
        return data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    
    console.log(data);
```

3

```
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    const getData = async ()=>{

        
        var response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
            return result;
        });

        setData(response)
        return response;
    }

    getData();

    console.log(data);
```

OBS: I'm inside of a React Component and wanna to use the data inside of the returning TML

How do I do to return the data from the then() function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetching data with axios in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228930/fetching-data-with-axios-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `useState` to assign the response from `then` function

first define it

```
const [apiData,setData] = useState(null)
```

then in the request

#### update:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then( res => setData(res))
```

after that

```
  console.log(apiData)//the useState value
```

whole code

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
useEffect(()=>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(res=> 
    setData(res.data));
 },[])
```

Now whenever you send a request and get response, `then`  function add the response to `data`

Comment: but this broke the code again, with the error: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable. at C:\Users\refba\github\nextJsTest\.next\server\pages\timeLine.js:4071:10 at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5.

Comment: and if I fix this, still returning "null" the old value

Comment: Yes I tryed it. But now it returs "null"

Comment: what if you remove return like i did in new updated answer?

Comment: I remove it, still returning null.... I think need to use setState

Comment: if you're using `then()` no need to use async await you should call the request in useeffect I'm updating the answer

Comment: important : make sure you `setData(res.data)` and not `setData(res)` do this and tell me the result

Comment: do you use the `data` somewhere inside your react component(except for console.log)? if you do try to remove it and rerun the app

Comment: I think it's work. Will try somt other things. Thanks <3

Comment: i'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

1. async/await

```
var data;

data = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
    return result;
});
```

2. by using promise, you can not get the result from the axios call.

Comment: Forgot to put json, you should return json from result from the first `then`.

Answer (score 0):

Axios performs an asynchronous request and therefore it's return value is not the actual data but it returns a promise object. If you want to access the data obtained by axios outside the get request, you can make use of the promise object returned by axios.

Here is an example snippet:

```
function getSrc() {   
    return axios.get('assist/img/src');
}

getSrc.then(function (response) {
    return response.data; // now the data is accessable from here.
}).catch(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Axios is designed this way so that it can help with asynchronous tasks. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: it says that  getSrc.then is not a function... (i'm inside of a react component)

Answer (score 0):

actually when you do it this way:

```js
var data;

data = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
    return result
});

console.log(data)
```

the data is not readily available at that time, and it will log Promise object.
If youre doing it inside a function, you can use `async`-`await` reserved keywords to wait for the value (remember, you can only use `await` inside `async` function)

```js
function async getData(){
var data;

data = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/goodNews').then(result => {
    return result
});

console.log(data)
}
```

but, technically youre still using Promise but in different form.